# C: connecting a program with the shutdown

Tags: c, windows, shutdown

Is there any possibility to connect a program with the shutdown in C so when i press the shutdown button the program running in the background stops and saves everything it has done?
I know how to stop and save the program but i have absolutely no idea how to connect it with clicking the shutdown button. 
Thx for every answer!

Comment: [WM_ENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can get shutdown notifications via [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WM_ENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889(v=vs.85).aspx).  More information is available in the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376881(v=vs.85).aspx).